# How to create a grid of numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to create a grid of numbers from 1 to 30. And I can decide which number I would like to cross out by replacing it with an 'X'. But I can't even print out the grid in char[][].

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9 X 11 12
>
> 13 14 15 16 17 18
>
> 19 20 21 22 23 24
>
> 25 26 27 28 X 30

the program gives me

```
123456
678911
111111
111122
222222
```

How do I solve this? Thanks!

```
int i, j, x;
char plan[6][5];

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            x = i*5+j+1;
            sprintf(&plan[i][j], "%d", x);
        }
        
    

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        printf("%c", plan[i][j]);
    printf("\n")    ;
}
```

Comment: The first parameter to `sprintf()` should be a a `char*` pointer. Not a single character.

Comment: Why are you using sprintf there? Don't you just want `plan[i][j] = x`? (or `x & 255`)

Comment: Fyi, your loops don't match your dimensions. the inner loop indexing 0..6 on a sequence that is only `[5]` will invoke *undefined behavior*, though I harbor a reasonable suspicion this isn't the *real* code.

Comment: yes, i want plan [i][j] to save the value of x. but 'plan[i][j] = x' is not working. cuz plan is char[][]? idk. If plan is int[][], its ok. I hvn't tried x%255.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/pLYiMi)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY OMG Thanks so much!!!! Problem solved. Im a beginner in c n i hv to hand in my project after 2days. Thanks guys!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)..The first argument should be a pointer, but you are passing a character, which will give you error: invalid conversion from `char` to `char*`. Better you should use `&plan[i][j]`..But it will store only one digit, to resolve this issue you may consider each element of the grid as a string.(I don't think it will be an appropriate way, But it will yield the desired output).

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
    int i, j, x;
    char plan[5][6][3];

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            {
                x = i*6+j+1;
                sprintf(plan[i][j], "%d", x);
            }



    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            printf("%s ", plan[i][j]);
        printf("\n")    ;
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I decide to use a 3D array to store 2 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

For the question at hand, you need to get a pointer to the location you are trying to put the values.  Use `&` to get the address:

`sprintf(&plan[i][j], "%d", x);`

However once you do that, you will discover a new problem.  Your 2D array of chars will only store one character in each location.  In the case of double-digit numbers, this will be a problem.

Comment: Yay exactly. How can i deal with it. Im crazy r8 now.

Comment: One option would be to have a 2D array of `char *` so each location in the 2D array would lead to a string that could be large enough to hold the number you wish to put into it (plus the terminating character).


Another option could be to rethink your process and store them as `int` and use a value that is out of the range of expected values (for example a negative number) to denote an 'X'

Answer (score 0):

Ok this took a while :

In your question, first big error of your code is this :
It should be `plan[5][6]` and not `plan[6][5]`

Instead of using a 3d array and utilizing more memory, a simple alternative would be to use the data type `string` as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
int i, j, x;
string plan[5][6];

x=1;//note that i increment this after every j loop is over
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
            char out[5];
            sprintf(out,"%d",x);

            plan[i][j].assign(out);
            x+=1;//note that i increment this after every j loop is over
        }
}

for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        printf(" %s ", plan[i][j].c_str());   
    printf("\n")    ;
}

}
```

And for putting `x` as stated in your question, you can simply do. `plan[i][j].assign("x")`